# Hide previous opened p tag after clicking new h3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made this show hide example where when i click on `h3` then description that is `p` tag will be show but here i'm getting problem. I want to hide previous `p` which opened after click on new `h3`. Any solution for it? I'm not getting it. Please help.

```js
$("h3").click(function(){
 $(this).next("p").toggle("slow");
});
```

```css
p{display:none;}
.f,.s{float:left;margin:10px}
h2{margin:0px}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="f">
<h2>
Web Development
</h2>
<ul>
<li><h3>
edfdfs
</h3>
<p>
jkksfhskhsdf hf dh dhffsdh hfdd s
</p>
</li>
<li><h3>
fsfsf sd 
</h3>
<p>
jhjsdhfsjkf hdsjfhh dh shds khsdk sd
</p></li>
<li><h3>
dfsdfdfs
</h3>
<p>
kdhs hkdhj djh sdh sdkh
</p></li>
<li><h3>
dcsdcs
</h3>
<p>
kjsdjjskd
</p></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="s">
<h2>
Web Development
</h2>
<ul>
<li><h3>
edfdfs
</h3>
<p>
jkksfhskhsdf hf dh dhffsdh hfdd s
</p>
</li>
<li><h3>
fsfsf sd 
</h3>
<p>
jhjsdhfsjkf hdsjfhh dh shds khsdk sd
</p></li>
<li><h3>
dfsdfdfs
</h3>
<p>
kdhs hkdhj djh sdh sdkh
</p></li>
<li><h3>
dcsdcs
</h3>
<p>
kjsdjjskd
</p></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="t">
<h2>
Web Development
</h2>
<ul>
<li><h3>
edfdfs
</h3>
<p>
jkksfhskhsdf hf dh dhffsdh hfdd s
</p>
</li>
<li><h3>
fsfsf sd 
</h3>
<p>
jhjsdhfsjkf hdsjfhh dh shds khsdk sd
</p></li>
<li><h3>
dfsdfdfs
</h3>
<p>
kdhs hkdhj djh sdh sdkh
</p></li>
<li><h3>
dcsdcs
</h3>
<p>
kjsdjjskd
</p></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you use `toggle` you simply need to hide other `p` but not the next `p`

```
$("h3").click(function(){
    $('.f p').not($(this).next("p")).hide();
    $(this).next("p").toggle("slow");
});
```

**Demo 1** *if you need to hide the other `p` inside each `parent` div*

```js
$("h3").click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.containDiv').find('p').not($(this).next("p")).slideUp();
 $(this).next("p").slideToggle();
});
```

```css
p{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="f containDiv">
  <h2>Web Development</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h3>edfdfs</h3>
      <p>jkksfhskhsdf hf dh dhffsdh hfdd s</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>edfdfs</h3>
      <p>jkksfhskhsdf hf dh dhffsdh hfdd s</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>edfdfs</h3>
      <p>jkksfhskhsdf hf dh dhffsdh hfdd s</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>edfdfs</h3>
      <p>jkksfhskhsdf hf dh dhffsdh hfdd s</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="s containDiv">
  <h2>Web Development</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h3>edfdfs</h3>
      <p>jkksfhskhsdf hf dh dhffsdh hfdd s</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>edfdfs</h3>
      <p>jkksfhskhsdf hf dh dhffsdh hfdd s</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>edfdfs</h3>
      <p>jkksfhskhsdf hf dh dhffsdh hfdd s</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>edfdfs</h3>
      <p>jkksfhskhsdf hf dh dhffsdh hfdd s</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="t containDiv">
  <h2>Web Development</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h3>edfdfs</h3>
      <p>jkksfhskhsdf hf dh dhffsdh hfdd s</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>edfdfs</h3>
      <p>jkksfhskhsdf hf dh dhffsdh hfdd s</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>edfdfs</h3>
      <p>jkksfhskhsdf hf dh dhffsdh hfdd s</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>edfdfs</h3>
      <p>jkksfhskhsdf hf dh dhffsdh hfdd s</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Demo 2** *if you need to hide all `p` inside all divs*

```js
$("h3").click(function(){
  $('.containDiv').find('p').not($(this).next("p")).slideUp();
 $(this).next("p").slideToggle();
});
```

```css
p{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="f containDiv">
  <h2>Web Development</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h3>edfdfs</h3>
      <p>jkksfhskhsdf hf dh dhffsdh hfdd s</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>edfdfs</h3>
      <p>jkksfhskhsdf hf dh dhffsdh hfdd s</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>edfdfs</h3>
      <p>jkksfhskhsdf hf dh dhffsdh hfdd s</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>edfdfs</h3>
      <p>jkksfhskhsdf hf dh dhffsdh hfdd s</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="s containDiv">
  <h2>Web Development</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h3>edfdfs</h3>
      <p>jkksfhskhsdf hf dh dhffsdh hfdd s</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>edfdfs</h3>
      <p>jkksfhskhsdf hf dh dhffsdh hfdd s</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>edfdfs</h3>
      <p>jkksfhskhsdf hf dh dhffsdh hfdd s</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>edfdfs</h3>
      <p>jkksfhskhsdf hf dh dhffsdh hfdd s</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="t containDiv">
  <h2>Web Development</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h3>edfdfs</h3>
      <p>jkksfhskhsdf hf dh dhffsdh hfdd s</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>edfdfs</h3>
      <p>jkksfhskhsdf hf dh dhffsdh hfdd s</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>edfdfs</h3>
      <p>jkksfhskhsdf hf dh dhffsdh hfdd s</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>edfdfs</h3>
      <p>jkksfhskhsdf hf dh dhffsdh hfdd s</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @SagarKodte glad it helped .. Have a great day :-)

Comment: can it be possible to close previous p smoothly?

Comment: @SagarKodte answer updated with two demos to suit your need .. please check it .. And don't forget to give the parent divs the same class .. Good Luck :-)

Comment: @SagarKodte *smoothly* you can use `slideUp()` OR `fadeOut()` instead of `hide()`

Comment: @SagarKodte also you can use `slideToggle()` instead of just `toggle()` if you got an issue with `toggle()`